# Function Not Called on click?

Tags: javascript

Simple Madblib project. Or so I thought. This is probably an easy fix but I'd greatly appreciate any help, I can't seem to get it to work correctly.

The function isn't called when button is clicked. Any suggestions? I've tried changing location of function and form, as well as adjusting "" on the input string.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <script>
    < head >
    script language = "JavaScript" >

    function Mission() {

        var a1 = document.AgentID.elements[0].value;
        var a2 = document.City.elements[0].value;
        var a3 = document.Country.elements[0].value;
        var a4 = document.Utensil.elements[0].value;
        var a5 = document.Adj1.elements[0].value;
        var a6 = document.Animal.elements[0].value;
        var a7 = document.Transportation.elements[0].value;

        document.write("<br>" + "<br>")
        document.write("Congradulations on accepting your next assignment Agent " + a1 + "")
        document.write("<br>" + "<br>")
        document.write("Your flight leaves to " + a2 + " , " + a3 + " in the next eight hours. You have been granted your weapon of choice, the " + a5 + " " + a4 + ". Your assignment is to capture the " + a6 + " with minimal casualties. Your extraction via " + a7 + " will be waiting.")
        document.write("<br>" + "<br>")
        document.write("Best of Luck Agent " + a1 + "")
        document.write("<br>")
        document.write("Operations HQ")
    }
    </script>

    </head>

    <body>
    <form id="AgentID" name="AgentID">
    AgentID <input type="text">
    </form>
    <form id="City" name="City">
    City <input type="text">
    </form>
    <form id="Country" name="Country">
    Country <input type="text">
    </form>
    <form id="Utensil" name="Utensil">
    Noun <input type="text">
    </form>
    <form id="Adj1" name="Adj1">
    Adjective <input type="text">
    </form>
    <form id="Animal" name="Animal">
    Animal <input type="text">
    </form>
    <form id="Transportaion" name="Transportaion">
    Transportation <input type="text">
    </form>
    <form>

    <input type="button" value="Accept" onClick="Mission()">

    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors? That stray "script" thing at the top is probably the problem.

Comment: Your code is very messy. What is your goal? What do you want the function to do? Please clarify your question

Comment: change `form id="Transportaion" name="Transportaion"`, you misspelled it. In your JS you call ***Transportation***, but in your HTML it's ***Transportaion***. It's simple *Transportation != Transportaion*

Comment: Wow. Embarrassing. Thank you so much, works great now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of issues in your code.

1. HTML is not valid. The tags are not missing structure. `Script` needs to be either in `head` or `body`.
2. You are NOT using the same name for `Transportation` in the javascript as you do in the HTML.

Following should work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
 <head>
  
    
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function Mission() {

        var a1 = document.AgentID.elements[0].value;
        var a2 = document.City.elements[0].value;
        var a3 = document.Country.elements[0].value;
        var a4 = document.Utensil.elements[0].value;
        var a5 = document.Adj1.elements[0].value;
        var a6 = document.Animal.elements[0].value;
        var a7 = document.Transportation.elements[0].value;

        document.write("<br>" + "<br>")
        document.write("Congradulations on accepting your next assignment Agent " + a1 + "")
        document.write("<br>" + "<br>")
        document.write("Your flight leaves to " + a2 + " , " + a3 + " in the next eight hours. You have been granted your weapon of choice, the " + a5 + " " + a4 + ". Your assignment is to capture the " + a6 + " with minimal casualties. Your extraction via " + a7 + " will be waiting.")
        document.write("<br>" + "<br>")
        document.write("Best of Luck Agent " + a1 + "")
        document.write("<br>")
        document.write("Operations HQ")
    }
    </script>

    </head>

    <body>
    <form id="AgentID" name="AgentID">
    AgentID <input type="text">
    </form>
    <form id="City" name="City">
    City <input type="text">
    </form>
    <form id="Country" name="Country">
    Country <input type="text">
    </form>
    <form id="Utensil" name="Utensil">
    Noun <input type="text">
    </form>
    <form id="Adj1" name="Adj1">
    Adjective <input type="text">
    </form>
    <form id="Animal" name="Animal">
    Animal <input type="text">
    </form>
    <form id="Transportation" name="Transportation">
    Transportation <input type="text">
    </form>
    <form>

    <input type="button" value="Accept" onClick="Mission()">

    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Just for fun, you could wrap up all those variables in a one liner and be done with them! `var arr = Array.prototype.map.apply(document.forms, [ function(v, i) { var e = v.children[0]; if (!(/accept/i.test(e.id))) this['a'+(i+1)] = e.value; return e.value; } ]);` [See? **:P**](https://jsfiddle.net/bfwr29xb/)

Comment: lol, np. Keep in mind, it would take a little tweaking if the HTML were correct and all inputs were in one form, not a new form for each input.